# Tournure "c'est... que..."

Tags: grammaire, stylistique

Bonjour,

Dans l'épigraphe de *Le Petit Chose* d'Alphonse Daudet :

> C'est un de mes maux **que** les souvenirs que me donnent les lieux :
> j'en suis frappée au-delà de la raison.

La phrase est atribuée à Madame de Sévigné.

À quoi sert le premier *que* dans *que les souvenirs...* ?

Comment: Et la phrase est de Mme de Sévigné, citée par Daudet.

Comment: Oui, merci ! j'ai édité la question. Est-ce que tu pourrais m'expliquer ce "que" exclamatif, s'il te plaît ? Je n'arrive pas à comprendre

Comment: C'est pas exclamatif du tout je disais une bêtise mais je vais essayer d'expliquer, la phrase est mal foutue au possible. Mme de Sévigné écrit mal et ponctue mal. Voir la lettre de Mme de Sévigné à Mme de Grignan (29 janvier 1674) on la trouve sur google books.

Comment: Merci. Je ne savais pas qu'elle écrivait mal. Proust et Céline louent beaucoup le style de Sévigné, mais je ne l'ai pas encore lu.

Answer (score 5):

On peut reformuler cette phrase (alambiquée, mais c'est du Sévigné...) comme suit:

> Les souvenirs que me donnent les lieux sont un de mes maux.

La construction (assez littéraire) "c'est... que..." + attribut est une construction emphatique, destinée à mettre en évidence une partie de la phrase.

Autres exemples:

> C'est une belle fleur que celle-ci.

> C'est un monstre que cet homme.

> C'est une jolie maison que la vôtre.

> C'est un des mes privilèges que pouvoir passer avant les autres.

On retrouve en fait ce "que" destiné à mettre en évidence dans la construction interrogative courante "qu'est-ce **que**..."

Comment: C'est une bonne réponse que la vôtre.

Comment: « C'est un **de** mes privilèges que ***de*** pouvoir passer avant les autres. » — Le premier *de* est une correction, le second, une suggestion quand *de* est suivi par un verbe (lui aussi suivi d'un second verbe qui est lui aussi à l'infinitif :-)

Answer (score 1):

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que))
> **I.** − **Empl. conjonctionnels**
> **A.** − **Conj. de sub.**
> **5.** [Introd. une complét. en fonction d'appos.]
> […]
> **c)** **[Apposée à un groupe nom. qui fait office de thème, la complt., réduite à un groupe nom., joue le rôle de prédicat]**
> ♦ Quelle belle fleur que la rose!

Mme de Sévigné écrivait au 17<sup>e</sup> siècle et son français est diffile à lire en raison des nombreuses tournures désuètes qu'il contient mais son usage de « que » est toujours moderne.

Cet usage n'est pas limité au présentatif, comme le montre l'exemple du TLFi, et on le trouve aussi en association à des tournures exclamatives. Ce qui suit « que » n'est pas un attribut (on ne connait en grammaire que l'attribut du sujet ou du cod),  mais une complétive en fonction d'apposition (« souvenirs » apposé à « maux » (qui fait office de thème)).

([réf. 1, 1828](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_mal_du_pays_ou_la_bateliere_de_Brienz/7O1KAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22pays+que+le+notre%22&pg=PA13&printsec=frontcover)) Et puis ce paysage, n'est-ce pas que c'est un beau pays que le nôtre ?

([réf. 2, 2015](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Aux_pays_des_deux_Nils/EECCCAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22pays+que+le+notre%22&pg=PT187&printsec=frontcover)) Ah ! c'est un bon pays que le nôtre ! Le doura n'y manque pas ! »

([réf. 3, 1829](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_Globe_Paris_1824/RfXTWE6Zlv8C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22pays+que+le+notre%22&pg=PA549&printsec=frontcove)) Oh ! le beau pays que le nôtre , avec la charte de moins et les ouvrages de M. Marolles

([réf. 4, 1993](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_moulin_de_la_Dhuys_Fran%C3%A7ois_Veyrat_p/77ZYDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quel+jour+heureux+que+celui%22&pg=PT237&printsec=frontcover)) Quel jour heureux que celui-ci ! Venez, il y a de ce côté une auberge tranquille où vous pourrez vous reposer ;

([réf. 5, 2015](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Nous/MVt4BwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quel+jour+heureux+que+celui%22&pg=PT167&printsec=frontcover)) La soirée terminée, elle rentrait chez moi à 2, 3 ou 4 heures du matin avec sa propre clé – quel jour heureux que celui où je lui avais fait fabriquer ce double ! –, grimpait dans mon lit sans un mot, le corps chaud, des traînées de ...

- C'est un de mes maux que les souvenirs que me donnent les lieux.

On pourrait trouver cette phrase lourde mais elle n'est pas autre chose que compliquée ; après simplification on a ceci :  « C'est mon mal que les souvenirs. ».

Il se trouve que ce mal n'est pas le seul dans l'esprit de la personne qui écrit, ce qui la force à écrire plutôt  « un des mes maux », et il se trouve que les souvenirs ne sont pas tous les souvenirs mais seulement « les souvenirs donnés par les lieux » ; ajouté à cela,  pour introduire cette dernière précision on utilise encore la forme « que », en tant que pronom relatif cette fois, et  ce faisant on force le lecteur à analyser une autre occurence et fonction de cette forme, le problème dans cette analyse étant que le premier « que » ne peut pas être analysé avant d'avoir lu jusqu'à « lieux », où on sait alors que le second « que » est un relatif et que « les souvenirs … lieux » est un groupe nominal ; si par manque d'habitude, c'est à dire par manque de lecture, le lecteur n'est pas rompu à la gymnastique de la détermination  des rapports grammaticaux, il est alors enclin à interpréter la difficulté comme de la lourdeur, mais il n'en est rien.

Remplacer cette phrase de Madame de Sévigné par une autre, dans laquelle le présentatif est supprimé, (comme j'ai pu en trouver l'idée dans une autre réponse (Les souvenirs que me donnent les lieux sont un de mes maux.)), supprime en même temps l'effet d'accentuation que cette tournure est sensé apporter à l'énonciation, et déforme la pensée de l'auteur.

> ([wikipédia, présentatif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9sentatif)) En linguistique, on appelle « présentatif »  un mot ou une structure syntaxique employé pour introduire ou poser l'existence d'un élément nouveau dans le discours. Typiquement, l’entité ainsi introduite sera élevée au statut de topique dans le discours qui suit.

> ([AlloPro](https://www.alloprof.qc.ca/fr/eleves/bv/francais/la-fonction-complement-du-presentatif-f1257)) Le présentatif est un mot ou une locution qui sert à introduire un élément nouveau sur lequel on souhaite mettre l'accent dans le discours.